# Literature Request: Conformal Field Theory for 1D XXZ Chain

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, fermions, spin-chains

It is known that the Heisenberg XXZ chain in 1D

\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = - J \sum_{i=1}^N \left(S^x_jS^x_{j+1} + S^y_jS^y_{j+1} + \Delta S^z_jS^z_{j+1}\right)
\end{equation}

can be described by the compactified boson CFT (for $-1 \le \Delta \le 1$), and is related to spinless fermion model by a Jordan-Wigner transformation. I would like to know some references (favorably pedagogical ones including details) that derived this result (compactified boson CFT from XXZ). I also believe that there is information loss when mapping from spinless fermion to XXZ chain; references that explain this loss in detail are also welcomed.

Comment: The exact Luttinger parameters for the XXZ chain in its Luttinger liquid phase are obtained by matching with Bethe Ansatz. The books *Quantum Field Theory in Condensed Matter Physics* by Alexei Tsvelik and *Quantum Physics in One Dimension* by Thierry Giamarchi give the exact Luttinger parameters, though they simply reference the papers which performed the Bethe Ansatz calculations.